# App cannot sign in to Firebase due to key restrictions?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying use Firebase Auth sign-in for an Android app (and later for an iOS version) and the server keeps rejecting the attempt. The following exception shows up in logcat whenever a sign-in is attempted (this was for a Google sign-in attempt; a similar thing happens with email/password sign-in):

```
Firebase sign in with credential google.com unsuccessful. Visit https://console.firebase.google.com to enable it.  
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ The Android package name and signing-certificate fingerprint, [package name removed] and [fingerprint removed], do not match the app restrictions configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions. ]
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxm.zzao(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwn.zza(Unknown Source)  
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxx.zzap(Unknown Source)  
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdya.onFailure(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxo.onTransact(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

I've checked the Firebase console and three sign-in methods are enabled: Google, Email / Password, and Anonymous. (I haven't tried anonymous sign-in yet.) I've also checked the project settings, and the package name and SHA-1 fingerprint displayed in the exception exactly match what's displayed in the console.

I'm using the following to start the sign-in flow:

```
public void signIn() {
    final List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build()
    );
    startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                  .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                  .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                  .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN
    );
}
```

The sign-in flow gets as far as prompting the user to select the Google account to be used, but then it dies with the above exception.

Here are the dependencies from my build.gradle file:

```
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '27.1.0'
    playServicesVersion = '11.8.0'
    firebaseUIVersion = '3.2.2'
    butterKnifeVersion = '8.8.1'
}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        // this next avoids a findbugs version conflict with
        // com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android
        exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    })

    // ButterKnife
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterKnifeVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterKnifeVersion"

    // Support libraries
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    // Firestore
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:$playServicesVersion"

    // FirebaseUI
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:$firebaseUIVersion"

    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.3'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev72-1.22.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I've downloaded a fresh google-services.json file for the project and I've cleaned and rebuilt the project. These steps didn't help.

I've tried exactly the same sign-in method with another project and everything works fine. The only difference I can think of between the two projects is that the one that works was created in the Firebase console, while this one that doesn't work was created in the Google Cloud console and later imported into the Firebase console when we decided to incorporate some Firebase functionality into the app.

If the only solution is to delete the app and re-create it directly in the Firebase console, I'll do that. However, we've done a lot of configuration of the project (through the Google Cloud console) and I'd like to avoid this step if possible.

**EDIT** So I created a new project in the Firebase console using a different package name and enabled the same sign-in methods. I then (temporarily) changed the package name in my build.gradle file. The modified app signs in just fine. So the problem definitely seems to be with the project configuration in the Firebase console, not on the client side. At this point, I strongly suspect that the problem has to do with the fact that the project is imported from the Google Cloud console.

Comment: do you have `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of gradle file?

Comment: @PeterHaddad - Sure do. The project won't build if that isn't there.

Comment: Have you configured your Sha hashes correctly?

Comment: @SUPERCILEX - Yes I did. I double checked the hashes when the project was first imported from the Google Cloud console. (And the non-Firebase API calls, including Google Sign-In, were working fine before I switched to Firebase Auth.)

Comment: And you're sure the Google provider is enabled?

Comment: @SUPERCILEX - Yes.

Comment: Then I would probably just file a support ticket.

Comment: @TedHopp What ended up being the issue? Any clues?

Comment: @RedM - I have no idea. I eventually just went with using a fresh Firebase project. For us, it was easier to start from scratch than to figure out how to get a project imported from Google Cloud to work properly.

Comment: I finally got it working. There was a file that is auto generated /Users/myName/Documents/workspace/Android/MyApp/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml that continuously contained the old api key even after having a new google-services.json file. What I did is I had to rebuild and clean the project, then that file got updated. After that, everything was working fine.

Comment: @RedM - Good to know. I'll try that if the situation comes up again for us. Thanks.